# How to confirm a user email address in android app programmatically

Tags: android

I have a register page in my app and on registration page user has to provide his/her email address, how can I confirm that email address whether it's an existing email address or fake one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- Send a mail with a validation key or a link the user should click.

2- Send a mail and verify if the server responds OK (via your mailer log maybe?)

I would go with 1 as a lot of site does

Note that site like junkmail or yopmail allow to have "fake" email account (not really fake but you have access to all accounts without password).

If people don't want you to have their email account, so what? If your content is interesting enough they'll happily give you the right one.

Answer (score -1):

this code helps you to understand if the email is valid or not but of course doesn't tell you if it does exists:

```
 /*
 * Checks if an email is valid using the system matcher
 */
public static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
    return !TextUtils.isEmpty(target) && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();
}
```

Comment: This does not answer OP's question.

Answer (score -1):

This check if it is a valid format email.

Code:

```
private String EMAIL_REGEX = "^[\\w-_\\.+]*[\\w-_\\.]\\@([\\w]+\\.)+[\\w]+[\\w]$";

if (edit_email.getText().toString().trim().matches(EMAIL_REGEX)) {
    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Valid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Invalid format", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Comment: This does not answer OP's question.